# How can I eliminate overlapping subtitles in VLC media player?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I am trying to watch a video with subtitles in VLC media player. But subtitles are overlapping making them difficult to read. How can I fix this? :

[image]

PS: video file is `.mp4`, subtitles file is `.srt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't push subtitles out of the frame, so your best bet may be to move them to the top of the frame.

Tools > Preferences > Subtitles > Force subtitle position, then set something approximating the height of your frame, in pixels. You need to relaunch VLC for the change to take effect.

[image]

*After comments…* the .srt file is mis-timed. Off times are far past the next on time, so the subs just overlay each other…

> [image]

Compared to a file with correct timings, first line off before next line on…

> [image]

I don't know of any automatic way to fix this - but, I'm not a subs editor. There may be a software solution I'm unaware of.

Comment: That didnt help, they still overlap, but at the top: [screenshot](https://postimg.cc/PNCqDGWC)

Comment: Ah, I couldn't see you meant multiple lines overlap from the first image - I thought you meant overlapping the text in the video itself. That's a file error, not a player error. You need to ask whoever made the subs file. [Outside chance… post the video link, if it's public, I'll have a look]

Comment: Video can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7_jFxTtJEo). [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SyLSkh0pWqpx_CgkiQwJvcUr9v5eT1pp/view?usp=sharing) is the subtitle file I am using. I just realised the coursera course now offer subtittles in VTT file format, which gets rendered correctly (without overlapping) in VLC. But still want to know how can I render above SRT without overlapping as I have course downloaded with all subtitles in SRT format.

Comment: The srt file is just really badly made, the off times for each line just massively overlap the on times for the next lines. As far as I can see, the only 'fix' is to go through it a line at a time & fix the off times. Added to answer.